# How can I search Xcode build Phases?

Tags: ios, xcode, search

I have a script that is different for each target.

I'm trying to search for parts of the script. ( I copy the value from the build phase itself and then search it in Xcode's 'Find Navigator')

Yet I don't see anything in Xcode. I'm guessing Xcode excludes the build Phases scripts.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I can see the info you're looking for in the _.pbxproj_ file. Open it with a good text editor and you'll see. So you could learn to parse that.

Comment: Another option is to just call a script from the Build phase i.e. have the code in an external shell and then just reference it externally

Comment: It's crazy, why an IDE like Xcode can't even search for text in the .pbxproj file

Comment: They should at least make it an option.